# how to apply pauli string depending on multiple control qubits (qiskit or stim)

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, stim

I read and re-read the documentation for MCMT and MCX and still can't figure out how to do this.
For example I have 10 qubits $q_0,\cdots q_9$; I want to apply pauli string $X_2 Y_4 Z_5$ with control bits $q_7,q_9$. How would this be done? I don't think this can be done in stim since these gates are not clifford; am I right?

Comment: It's unclear to me if you're asking about how to do something in qiskit or if it can be done in stim. Questions should be one question.

Comment: @CraigGidney Actually both...I didn't think stim could do it based on non-clifford gate support...please correct if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that MCMT allows one type of target gate only (i.e you can apply an $X$ gate for example on multiple target qubits, but applying $X$ on that qubit and $Z$ on another qubit, for example - is not supported).

However we can write a piece of code that does that pretty easily:

```
def pauliStringCustomGate(qubits_span, gates_list, qubits_list):
    qc = QuantumCircuit(qubits_span)
    
    count = 0
    for g in gates_list:
        if g == 'X':
            qc.x(qubits_list[count])
        elif g == 'Y':
            qc.y(qubits_list[count])
        elif g == 'Z':
            qc.z(qubits_list[count])
        count += 1

    gate_qc = qc.to_gate(label = "Custom Pauli String")
    return gate_qc

cps = pauliStringCustomGate(qubits_span = 4, gates_list = ['X','Y','Z'], qubits_list = [0,2,3])
qc = QuantumCircuit(10)
qc.append(instruction = cps.control(num_ctrl_qubits = 2), qargs = [7,9,2,3,4,5])
```

The quantum circuit you get is:

[image]

And the content of the "Custom Pauli String" box is:

[image]

Comment: this also worked...it was a tossup to decide which answer to accept

Answer (score 4):

Qiskit provides [`PauliGate`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.PauliGate.html) which makes it really easy to achieve that:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import PauliGate

pauli_string = 'ZYX'
gate = PauliGate(pauli_string).control(2)
circ.append(gate, [7, 9, 2, 4, 5])
```

Where `circ` is you quantum circuit.

[image]

Comment: thanks, this worked

Answer (score 2):

Stim doesn't allow multiple controls.

Actually, it doesn't even allow combining multiple *classical* controls, though in most other contexts those are considered okay for stabilizer circuits. It's due to an underlying algorithmic issue, where samples produces by circuits with such operations lack a group structure that enables extremely fast bulk simulations.

This refers specifically to what can be put into a `stim.Circuit`. Obviously nothing prevents the python code driving a `stim.TableauSimulator` from making decisions that depend on multiple measurement results in complex ways.

Comment: I have to learn how you can still do QECC with this limitation...I think I'm missing some key ideas behind stim's approach.

Comment: @unknown You can't do universal computation under this constraint, even with magic states. But you can still determine what the error rates of those constructions would be.